# How do I move these objects independently of each other?

Tags: objects

I accidentally moved the particles away from the object (the donut) and saved it. They are connected with the option "object (keep transform) and I can't put the sprinkles back on the donut.
I need help. :D

[image]

Comment: From the Object menu, select Parent > Clear Parent with the sprinkles selected. You can also use [ALT] P.

Comment: Hello, I still can't move it. The icing and the particles move the same. Also the particles aren't an own object.

Comment: Ah right. It's a very long time since I followed the Donut tutorial so I'd forgotten that Andrew used a particle system for them. I'm afraid I've no idea what's happened in that case, but I'd suggest deleting the particle system and starting again from around 7:42 minutes in part 1 level 2 of his tutorial.

Comment: Alright, thanks!